# Pointer-to-member-function error

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to use a pointer to a member function in my code so that I can easily replace the function to use without changing everywhere in the code. I get an error while compiling that I don't understand how to solve. Here is a minimum working example:

**OrderBook.h**

```
#include <list>
#include <string>

class Order
{

};

class OrderBook
{
    typedef void(OrderBook::* MatchingAlgorithm)(Order&, std::list<Order>&);
public:
    OrderBook(const std::string name);    
    void ExecuteFunction(Order&, std::list<Order>);
private:
    void FunctionToUse(Order&, std::list<Order>&);        
    const std::string m_OrderBookName;
    MatchingAlgorithm m_matchingAlgorithm;
};
```

**OrderBook.cpp**

```
#include "OrderBook.h"

OrderBook::OrderBook(
    const std::string name
    )
    : m_OrderBookName(name)
{
    m_matchingAlgorithm = &OrderBook::FunctionToUse;
}

void OrderBook::ExecuteFunction(Order & order, std::list<Order> listOfOrders)
{
    (*m_matchingAlgorithm)(order, listOfOrders);
}

void OrderBook::FunctionToUse(Order &, std::list<Order>&)
{
    // do nothing
}
```

**Source.cpp**

```
#include "OrderBook.h"

int main() 
{
    std::list<Order> mylist;
    Order o1, o2;    
    mylist.push_back(o1);
    mylist.push_back(o2);

    OrderBook ob("my book");

    ob.ExecuteFunction(o1, mylist);

    return 0;
}
```

**Compilation Errors**

```
error C2171: '*': illegal on operands of type 'OrderBook::MatchingAlgorithm'
error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments
```

If I replace `(*m_matchingAlgorithm)` with `FunctionToUse` inside `ExecuteFunction` the code compiles without errors.

Comment: How would the function know what `this` is with that calling syntax? This is just a simple case of guessing at the syntax and the compiler telling you that you guessed wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the function call to:

```
(this->*m_matchingAlgorithm)(order, listOfOrders);
```

Comment: Thanks Sam, this works! But I cannot really understand the reason behind it. Could you write a few lines about how I should think for this to make sense?

Comment: All member functions have a hidden/implicit argument, of the type of the class theyre declared in. i.e. you need an instance of that class to call it. Thats why you need `this`.

Comment: @DoubleTrouble - "*pointer", by itself, works only for regular, ordinary pointers. The unary `*` operator is not defined for member function pointers. Member function pointers must be invoked using the `->*` operator: `object->*memberfunction`, with "object" specifying which object's method is to be invoked. Specifying the object is mandatory, it does not default to `this`.

Answer (score 2):

### Short answer

You can call your function using the pointer to member operator (`.*` or `->*`):

```
void OrderBook::ExecuteFunction(Order & order, std::list<Order> listOfOrders)
{
    (this->*m_matchingAlgorithm)(order, listOfOrders);
}
```

More info [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#fnptr-vs-memfnptr-types).

### Long explanations

We are all used to omit `this->` for accessing members of the current object.  The mecanism that allows this is name resolution principles.  But these do not apply for pointer dereferencing operators.

**The simple case of a pointer to a data member**

Let's star with a simpler case : a pointer to an integer member.

```
class OrederBook {
    ...
    int x,y; 
    int OrderBook::* px; 
};
```

In the constructor you couldn't initialize `px` with `&x` because `&x` is an absolute address of an integer, and `px` is the (relative) address of an integer in an `OrderBook`.  We would then initialize it:

```
OrderBook::OrderBook(..)
    : m_OrderBookName(name), px(&OrderBook::x) {...}
```

But in this case, the ordinary dereferencing operator for `px` would not work either:

```
 *px =2;    // error because of unary operator *
```

In fact, for dereferencing such a pointer, you need to know not only the pointer, but also the object in which this pointer should be used:

```
 this->*px =2;    // yes ! take relative px address and apply it to this object.
```

**Unary vs. Binary derefencing**

The standard defines two different dereferencing operators:

> **5.3.1/1:** The **unary** * operator performs indirection: the expression to which it
>   is applied shall be a pointer to an object type, or a pointer to a
>   function type and the result is an lvalue referring to the object or
>   function to which the expression points. If the type of the expression
>   is “pointer to T,” the type of the result is “T.”
>
> **5.5/3:** The **binary** operator ->* binds its second operand, which shall be of type “pointer to member of T” to its first operand, which
>   shall be of type “pointer to T” or “pointer to a class of which T is
>   an unambiguous and accessible base class.” The expression E1->*E2 is
>   converted into the equivalent form (*(E1)).*E2.

**Dereferencing a pointer to a member function**

For the data example above, you have the choice of the weapons.  You could build very easily code achieving the same results, but defining `px` as `int *px` instead of `int OrderBook::*px` and using the unary `*` as usual.

Unfortunately for poitners to non static member function, you can't use such shortcuts. You really need a pointer to a member function and not a pointer to a function:  When you call a member function, in addition to the arguments that you have to pass, you always have to know for which object you call it.  And the only way to tell this is to use `(->*)` or `(.*)`.

**Conclusion**

Ommitting `this->*` and assuming the compiler would be intelligent enough to deduct that it's for the current object could seem natural for us.  But this is not defined by the standard.  It's unfortunate and more [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#macro-for-ptr-to-memfn).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! However, I will accept Sam's answer since he was first.

Comment: @DoubleTrouble No problem ;-) I saw his answer only after refreshing.  I would have deleted mine, but I wanted to take opportunity to explain the reasons, just for the records (see edit).