# Compile error for function pointer to member function in C++

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I am getting compile error C2064 for this code.

```
class MainClass;

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();
    void (MainClass::*functionPointer)();
    void callback();
};

class MainClass
{
public:
    void testFunction();
    void setup();
    MyClass myClass;
};

void MainClass::testFunction()
{
}

void MainClass::setup()
{
    myClass.functionPointer = &MainClass::testFunction;
    myClass.callback();
}

void MyClass::callback()
{
    functionPointer();
};

int main() {
    MainClass mainClass;
    mainClass.setup();
    return(0);
}
```

I have tried:

- Changing the function call syntax to `this->functionPointer();`
- Explicitly casting functionPointer to a regular function pointer with the code:
  `void (*fp)(void) = (void (*)(void))this->functionPointer; fp();`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pointer-to-member-function error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38033305/pointer-to-member-function-error)

Comment: *What* error are you getting?

Comment: You need an instance of `MainClass` to call the `functionPointer` with. Your `MyClass` does not have access to any such instance in the current code

Comment: *I have tried:* -- Before embarking on using pointers to non-static member functions, [make sure you know how to use them](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members).  C++ is not the type of computer language where guessing will work.

Comment: What is C2064? This is not a standard error.

Comment: BTW: MainClass can't instantiate a MyClass member because it does not have a constructor implemented.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/fc6aGsqPb

Comment: @ScottHunter I am getting the error "C2064 term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments" for the line "functionPointer()".

Comment: @john Many thanks for your answer. I tried the code change you suggested, but get exactly the same compile error for the function invocation (term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments). The intention was for the testFunction pointer to be for instance of MainClass in which it was assigned to the pointer, i.e. the instance or MainClass for which setup() was called.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but member function pointers don't work in the way that you are trying to use them. In order to call a member function via a member function pointer you need an instance of the type that the member function is part of.

With the following code changes your code should work, not sure if this is what you want or not however.

```
void MainClass::setup()
{
    myClass.functionPointer = &MainClass::testFunction;
    myClass.callback(*this); // pass instance of MainClass to callback
}

void MyClass::callback(MainClass& mc)
{
    (mc.*functionPointer)(); // use passed instance to call member function
}
```

The `.*` operator is the way you call a member function using an object instance and member function pointer. There is a similar `->*` operator that takes and object pointer and member function pointer.